# PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials stops validating after IIS deployment works fine in cassini

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory

I have the following code snippet to test a plain-text username/password against the AD, which works fine if I hit F5 in visual studio and try it via the WCFTestClient, but once I deploy to IIS and try the same function, it will never return true for ValidCredentials; is there something security wise that needs to be set for the Identity that the Application Pool runs under?

I tried setting the App Pool identity to my own account (domain admin) just to test if this was the problem, but that didn't help either, so I'm a bit lost as to how to fix this.

The site (Custom API) has anonymous access set up.

```
try
{
    // create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too) 
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName))
    {
        // validate the credentials
        if (pc.ValidateCredentials(UserName, Password))
        {
            IsValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    LoggingControler.LogWarning(null, "Unreachable Domain: " + Domain);
}
```

I've gone over things again, and it's all due to Rights in Windows. Network Service somehow doesn't have enough rights to execute `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials`. If I change the Application Pool Identity to the identity of a Domain Administrator, the code works.

If someone can tell me how to set up a Limited User account with the proper rights to execute `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials`, I can finish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found my own answer via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140377/query-activedirectory-sometimes-not-working-asp-net-c and https://elgg.leeds.ac.uk/webteam/weblog/15385.html

As I've discovered, "Network Service" application pool identity holds the key to this problem...

Adding the read rights didn't work; so there's still something else wrong.

Comment: Even if you grant "Network Service" permission to read C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys, the AD itself may only allow queries by domain accounts. Is there a reason why you can't change the identity of the App Pool to a domain account?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable [Windows Authentication in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: No, it needs to work without; I manually validate the credentials. I've gone over things again, and it's all due to Rights in Windows. Network Service somehow doesn't have enought rights to execute PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials. If I change the Application Pool Identity to the identity of a Domain Administrator, the code works.